# Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock

Tags: popularity-contest

Create a function that will take two strings as input and return a single output for the result.  Most popular answer wins.

The rules of Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock are:

- Scissors cut paper
- Paper covers rock
- Rock crushes lizard
- Lizard poisons Spock
- Spock smashes scissors
- Scissors decapitate lizard
- Lizard eats paper
- Paper disproves Spock
- Spock vaporizes rock
- Rock breaks scissors

The output for every possible input case is:

```
winner('Scissors', 'Paper') -> 'Scissors cut Paper'
winner('Scissors', 'Rock') -> 'Rock breaks Scissors'
winner('Scissors', 'Spock') -> 'Spock smashes Scissors'
winner('Scissors', 'Lizard') -> 'Scissors decapitate Lizard'
winner('Scissors', 'Scissors') -> 'Scissors tie Scissors'
winner('Paper', 'Rock') -> 'Paper covers Rock'
winner('Paper', 'Spock') -> 'Paper disproves Spock'
winner('Paper', 'Lizard') -> 'Lizard eats Paper'
winner('Paper', 'Scissors') -> 'Scissors cut Paper'
winner('Paper', 'Paper') -> 'Paper ties Paper'
winner('Rock', 'Spock') -> 'Spock vaporizes Rock'
winner('Rock', 'Lizard') -> 'Rock crushes Lizard'
winner('Rock', 'Scissors') -> 'Rock breaks Scissors'
winner('Rock', 'Paper') -> 'Paper covers Rock'
winner('Rock', 'Rock') -> 'Rock ties Rock'
winner('Lizard', 'Rock') -> 'Rock crushes Lizard'
winner('Lizard', 'Spock') -> 'Lizard poisons Spock'
winner('Lizard', 'Scissors') -> 'Scissors decapitate Lizard'
winner('Lizard', 'Paper') -> 'Lizard eats Paper'
winner('Lizard', 'Lizard') -> 'Lizard ties Lizard'
winner('Spock', 'Rock') -> 'Spock vaporizes Rock'
winner('Spock', 'Lizard') -> 'Lizard poisons Spock'
winner('Spock', 'Scissors') -> 'Spock smashes Scissors'
winner('Spock', 'Paper') -> 'Paper disproves Spock'
winner('Spock', 'Spock') -> 'Spock ties Spock'
```

Extra challenge suggested by @Sean Cheshire: Allow custom lists, such as those from this site. With the n-item list, the item loses to the (n-1)/2 previous, and wins over the (n-1)/2 following

Comment: Creating a 25-element lookup table isn't a challenge, and being popular isn't a [tag:code-challenge].

Comment: Your example is inconsistent with verb forms - "Scissors cut" vs. "Scissors ties". Important?

Comment: @ugoren, I guess it should be "Scissors tie".  I could add an `'ScSc': 'tie'` entry.

Comment: @Peter Taylor, All code can be represented by a lookup table.  Programming is about creating code that is shorter than the most obvious table.

Comment: Most interesting problems have an unbounded number of possible inputs, and can't be represented by a finite lookup table. Creating a minimal perfect hash for this particular lookup table might be interesting, but if that's what you're looking for them it should be a code golf rather than a popularity contest.

Comment: And when I say that being popular isn't a [tag:code-challenge]: the explanation of that tag begins *A code challenge is a competition for creative ways to solve a programming puzzle for an objective criterion other than code size.* "Most popular answer wins" is not an objective criterion: you couldn't give the text of two answers to someone and ask them which is the most popular.

Comment: There are many code challenges on the site that are decided by upvotes without any criteria as to why someone should upvote.  You should be familiar with [this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6162/write-a-program-that-is-valid-after-circular-character-shift) .

Comment: @PeterTaylor, dansalmo is right, so long as that lookup table is in a loop: this is a famous theorem of Conway: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN

Comment: @dansalmo The challenge you link to was created before the existence of the [tag:popularity-contest] tag.

Comment: A suggestion to add to the challenge - Allow custom lists, such as those from [this site](http://www.umop.com/rps.htm) that go up to 101 items. With the n-item list, the item loses to the (n-1)/2 previous, and wins over the (n-1)/2 follwing

Comment: @primo, it would be helpful to new users if the more knowledgeable users could update the wiki to explain the popularity-contest tag and that it is mutually exclusive with code-challenge.

Comment: This would be a great challenge as a [tag:code-golf] [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge, but I'm going to vote to close it since there is no winning criteria or any good reason it should be a popularity contest.

Answer (score 13):

## APL

```
vs←{
    n←'Scissors' 'Paper' 'Rock' 'Lizard' 'Spock'
    x←n⍳⊂⍺ ⋄ y←n⍳⊂⍵ ⋄ X←⍺ ⋄ Y←⍵ ⋄ r←{X,⍵,⊂Y}
    x=y:     r (-x=0)↓'ties'
    y=5|1+x: r x⌷'cut' 'covers' 'crushes' 'poisons' 'smashes'
    y=5|3+x: r x⌷'decapitate' 'disproves' 'breaks' 'eats' 'vaporizes'
    ⍵∇⍺
}
```

Output exactly as required in all cases, including tie/ties. No lookup table, except for the actual words.

You can try it on http://ngn.github.io/apl/web/

```
'Spock' vs 'Paper'
Paper  disproves  Spock
```

APL just knows!

Comment: +1, Never noticed APL until now.  Mesmerizing. Your structure is also cool.  I like the last line the best.

Comment: @dansalmo Thanks :) I like it a lot. And now thanks to https://github.com/ngn/apl we have an open source and web-ready interpreter (for decades there were only commercial interpreters)

Comment: @dansalmo btw, APL is a perfect fit for the kind of functional coding you seem to be doing in Python (which I like to do as well)

Answer (score 10):

### SED

```
#!/bin/sed
#expects input as 2 words, eg: scissors paper

s/^.*$/\L&/
s/$/;scissors cut paper covers rock crushes lizard poisons spock smashes scissors decapitates lizard eats paper disproves spock vaporizes rock breaks scissors/
t a
:a
s/^\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\w\+\);.*\1 \(\w\+\) \2.*$/\u\1 \3 \u\2/
s/^\(\w\+\)\s\+\(\w\+\);.*\2 \(\w\+\) \1.*$/\u\2 \3 \u\1/
t b
s/^\(\w\+\)\s\+\1;\(\1\?\(s\?\)\).*$/\u\1 tie\3 \u\1/
:b
```

Comment: This is... diabolical.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a general solution based on a rule string of any size.  It performs correct capitalization for the proper name "Spock" and also allows rules for specifying 'tie' instead of 'ties' for plural objects.

```
def winner(p1, p2):
    rules = ('scissors cut paper covers rock crushes lizard poisons Spock'
    ' smashes scissors decapitate lizard eats paper disproves Spock vaporizes'
    ' rock breaks scissors tie scissors'.split())

    idxs = sorted(set(i for i, x in enumerate(rules) 
                      if x.lower() in (p1.lower(), p2.lower())))
    idx = [i for i, j in zip(idxs, idxs[1:]) if j-i == 2]
    s=' '.join(rules[idx[0]:idx[0]+3] if idx 
          else (rules[idxs[0]], 'ties', rules[idxs[0]]))
    return s[0].upper()+s[1:]
```

Results:

```
>>> winner('spock', 'paper')
'Paper disproves Spock'
>>> winner('spock', 'lizard')
'Lizard poisons Spock'
>>> winner('Paper', 'lizard')
'Lizard eats paper'
>>> winner('Paper', 'Paper')
'Paper ties paper'
>>> winner('scissors',  'scissors')
'Scissors tie scissors'
```

Comment: When defining `rules` you can use a multiline string instead of literal concatenation. This allow you to remove the redundant parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

### Python

```
class Participant (object):
    def __str__(self): return str(type(self)).split(".")[-1].split("'")[0]
    def is_a(self, cls): return (type(self) is cls)
    def do(self, method, victim): return "%s %ss %s" % (self, method, victim)

class Rock (Participant):
        def fight(self, opponent):
                return (self.do("break", opponent)  if opponent.is_a(Scissors) else
                        self.do("crushe", opponent) if opponent.is_a(Lizard)   else
                        None)

class Paper (Participant):
        def fight(self, opponent):
                return (self.do("cover", opponent)    if opponent.is_a(Rock)  else
                        self.do("disprove", opponent) if opponent.is_a(Spock) else
                        None)

class Scissors (Participant):
        def fight(self, opponent):
                return (self.do("cut", opponent)       if opponent.is_a(Paper)  else
                        self.do("decaitate", opponent) if opponent.is_a(Lizard) else
                        None)

class Lizard (Participant):
        def fight(self, opponent):
                return (self.do("poison", opponent) if opponent.is_a(Spock) else
                        self.do("eat", opponent)    if opponent.is_a(Paper) else
                        None)

class Spock (Participant):
        def fight(self, opponent):
                return (self.do("vaporize", opponent) if opponent.is_a(Rock)     else
                        self.do("smashe", opponent)    if opponent.is_a(Scissors) else
                        None)

def winner(a, b):
    a,b = ( eval(x+"()") for x in (a,b))
    return a.fight(b) or b.fight(a) or a.do("tie", b)
```

Comment: Scissors are plural, so "cut*s*" paper and "decaitate*s*" lizard" is wrong (the last one misses a P too) . And "Spock *smashs*" should be "smashes" ;)

Comment: @daniero, thanks. I noticed the scissors problem, but fixing it complicates things. Fixing "smashes" now.

Comment: @Daniel "Scissors" is plural.  "Scissors" is also singular. See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scissors

Comment: So subtle. Love it.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, arithmetic approach

The actors can can be arranged in an array in such a way that each actor `a[i]` wins against the actors `a[i+1]` and `a[i+2]`, modulo 5, for instance:

```
%w(Scissors Lizard Paper Spock Rock)
```

Then, for an actor `A` with index `i` we can see how he matches agains actor `B` with index `j` by doing `result = (j-i)%5`: Result `1` and `2` means that actor A won against an actor 1 or 2 places in front of him respectively; `3` and `4` similarly means he lost against an actor behind him in the array. `0` means a tie. (Note that this may be language dependent; in Ruby `(j-i)%5 == (5+j-i)%5` also when `j>i`.)

The most interesting part of my code is the use of this property to find a sorting function of the indices of two actors. The return value will be -1, 0 or 1 [as it should](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort):

```
winner,loser = [i,j].sort { |x,y| ((y-x)%5+1)/2-1 }
```

Here's the whole thing:

```
def battle p1,p2
    who = %w(Scissors Lizard Paper Spock Rock)
    how = %w(cut decapitate poisons eats covers disproves smashes vaporizes crushes breaks)
    i,j = [p1,p2].map { |s| who.find_index s }

    winner,loser = [i,j].sort { |x,y| ((y-x)%5+1)/2-1 }

    method = (winner-loser)%5/2
    what = method == 0 && "ties" || how[winner*2 + method-1]

    return "#{who[winner]} #{what} #{who[loser]}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python

```
def winner(p1, p2):
    actors = ['Paper', 'Scissors', 'Spock', 'Lizard', 'Rock']
    verbs = {'RoLi':'crushes', 'RoSc':'breaks', 'LiSp':'poisons',
             'LiPa':'eats', 'SpSc':'smashes', 'SpRo':'vaporizes', 
             'ScPa':'cut', 'ScLi':'decapitate', 'PaRo':'covers', 
             'PaSp':'disproves', 'ScSc':'tie'}
    p1, p2 = actors.index(p1), actors.index(p2)
    winner, loser = ((p1, p2), (p2, p1))[(1,0,1,0,1)[p1 - p2]]
    return ' '.join([actors[winner],
                     verbs.get(actors[winner][0:2] + actors[loser][0:2],
                               'ties'),
                     actors[loser]])
```

Comment: By the way, "looser" is the opposite of "tighter".  "Loser" is the opposite of "winner".  And it'll save you a few characters in your code.

Answer (score 2):

## Python

---

```
  def winner(p,q):
        if p==q:
           return(' '.join([p,'tie',q]))
        d = {'ca':'cut','ao':'covers','oi':'crushes','ip':'poisons','pc': 'smashes','ci':'decapitate','ia':'eats', 'ap':'disproves', 'po':'vaporizes','oc': 'breaks'}
        [a,b] = [p[1],q[1]]
        try:
           return(' '.join([p,d[a+b],q]))
        except KeyError:
           return(' '.join([q,d[b+a],p]))
```

Using a tricky dictionary.

Comment: Nice one.  `return(' '.join([p,'tie' + 's'*(p[1]!='c'),q]))` will get the verb tense correct.

Answer (score 2):

## C#

#### Assumptions

The opponents are arranged in an n-item array where players beat the (n-1)/2 players ahead of them and lose to the (n-1)/2 players behind them. *(With even length lists, the player loses to the ((n-1)/2 + 1) players behind them)*

Player actions are arranged in an array where actions within the range of [(indexOfPlayer * (n-1)/2)] to [(indexOfPlayer * (n-1)/2)) + (n-2)/2 - 1].

#### Additional Info

`CircularBuffer<T>` is a wrapper around an array to create an "infinitely" addressable array. The `IndexOf` function returns the index of an item within the actual bounds of the array.

#### The Class

```
public class RockPaperScissors<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private CircularBuffer<T> players;
    private CircularBuffer<T> actions;

    private RockPaperScissors() { }

    public RockPaperScissors(T[] opponents, T[] actions)
    {
        this.players = new CircularBuffer<T>(opponents);
        this.actions = new CircularBuffer<T>(actions);
    }

    public string Battle(T a, T b)
    {
        int indexA = players.IndexOf(a);
        int indexB = players.IndexOf(b);

        if (indexA == -1 || indexB == -1)
        {
            return "A dark rift opens in the side of the arena.\n" +
                   "Out of it begins to crawl a creature of such unimaginable\n" +
                   "horror, that the spectators very minds are rendered\n" +
                   "but a mass of gibbering, grey jelly. The horrific creature\n" +
                   "wins the match by virtue of rendering all possible opponents\n" +
                   "completely incapable of conscious thought.";
        }

        int range = (players.Length - 1) / 2;

        if (indexA == indexB)
        {
            return "'Tis a tie!";
        }
        else
        {
            indexB = indexB < indexA ? indexB + players.Length : indexB;
            if (indexA + range < indexB)
            {
                // A Lost
                indexB = indexB >= players.Length ? indexB - players.Length : indexB;
                int actionIndex = indexB * range + (indexA > indexB ? indexA - indexB : (indexA + players.Length) - indexB) - 1;

                return players[indexB] + " " + actions[actionIndex] + " " + players[indexA];
            }
            else
            {
                // A Won
                int actionIndex = indexA * range + (indexB - indexA) - 1;

                return players[indexA] + " " + actions[actionIndex] + " " + players[indexB];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
string[] players = new string[] { "Scissors", "Lizard", "Paper", "Spock", "Rock" };
string[] actions = new string[] { "decapitates", "cuts", "eats", "poisons", "disproves", "covers", "vaporizes", "smashes", "breaks", "crushes" };

RockPaperScissors<string> rps = new RockPaperScissors<string>(players, actions);

foreach (string player1 in players)
{
    foreach (string player2 in players)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rps.Battle(player1, player2));
    }
}
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, one-liner

```
winner=lambda a,b:(
    [a+" ties "+b]+
    [x for x in 
        "Scissors cut Paper,Paper covers Rock,Rock crushes Lizard,Lizard poisons Spock,Spock smashes Scissors,Scissors decapitate Lizard,Lizard eats Paper,Paper disproves Spock,Spock vaporizes Rock,Rock break Scissors"
        .split(',') 
     if a in x and b in x])[a!=b]
```

Comment: Very cool!  You can `.split(', ')` and not have to jam,the,rules,together.

Comment: @dansalmo, Thanks, But I see no harm in JammingTheRulesTogether. Though it isn't a golfing contest, I think the shorter the better.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small thing I came up with:

```
echo "winners('Paper', 'Rock')"|sed -r ":a;s/[^ ]*'([[:alpha:]]+)'./\1/;ta;h;s/([[:alpha:]]+) ([[:alpha:]]+)/\2 \1/;G"|awk '{while(getline line<"rules"){split(line,a," ");if(match(a[1],$1)&&match(a[3],$2))print line};close("rules")}' IGNORECASE=1
```

Here, rules is the file containing all the rules that were given.

Answer (score 0):

### Python

Inspired by @Tobia's APL code.

```
def winner(p1, p2):
  x,y = map(lambda s:'  scparolisp'.find(s.lower())/2, (p1[:2], p2[:2]))
  v = (' cut covers crushes poisons smashes'.split(' ')[x*(y in (x+1, x-4))] or
       ' decapitate disproves breaks eats vaporizes'.split(' ')[x*(y in (x+3, x-2))])
  return ' '.join((p1.capitalize(), v or 'tie'+'s'*(x!=1), p2)) if v or p1==p2 \
    else winner(p2, p1)
```

Results:

```
>>> winner('Spock', 'paper')
'Paper disproves Spock'
>>> winner('Spock', 'lizard')
'Lizard poisons Spock'
>>> winner('paper', 'lizard')
'Lizard eats paper'
>>> winner('paper', 'paper')
'Paper ties paper'
>>> winner('scissors',  'scissors')
'Scissors tie scissors'
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std ;
map<string,int> type = { {"Scissors",0},{"Paper",1},{"Rock",2},{"Lizard",3},{"Spock",4} };
map<pair<int,int>, string> joiner = {
  {{0,1}, " cuts "},{{0,3}, " decapitates "}, {{1,2}, " covers "},{{1,4}, " disproves "},
  {{2,3}, " crushes "},{{2,0}, " crushes "},  {{3,4}, " poisons "},{{3,1}, " eats "},
  {{4,0}, " smashes "},{{4,2}, " vaporizes "},
} ;
// return 0 if first loses, return 1 if 2nd wins
int winner( pair<int,int> p ) {
  return (p.first+1)%5!=p.second && (p.first+3)%5!=p.second ;
}
string winner( string sa, string sb ) {
  pair<int,int> pa = {type[sa],type[sb]};
  int w = winner( pa ) ;
  if( w )  swap(pa.first,pa.second), swap(sa,sb) ;
  return sa+(pa.first==pa.second?" Ties ":joiner[pa])+sb ;
}
```

A bit of a test

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  for( pair<const string&, int> a : type )
    for( pair<const string&, int> b : type )
      puts( winner( a.first, b.first ).c_str() ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

```
function winner(c1,c2){
    var c = ["Scissors", "Paper", "Rock", "Lizard", "Spock"];
    var method={
        1:["cut", "covers", "crushes", "poisons", "smashes"],
        2:["decapitate", "disproves", "breaks", "eats", "vaporizes"]};
    //Initial hypothesis: first argument wins
    var win = [c.indexOf(c1),c.indexOf(c2)];
    //Check for equality
    var diff = win[0] - win[1];
    if(diff === 0){
        return c1 + ((win[0]===0)?" tie ":" ties ") + c2;
    }
    //If s is -1 we'll swap the order of win[] array
    var s = (diff>0)?1:-1;
    diff = Math.abs(diff);
    if(diff >2){
        diff = 5-diff;
        s= s * -1;
    }
    s=(diff==1)?s*-1:s;
    if(s === -1){
        win = [win[1],win[0]];
    }
    return c[win[0]] + " " + method[diff][win[0]] + " " + c[win[1]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

I see this isn't a golfing contest, but I had been fiddling with this puzzle for a while before finding this thread, so here goes.

Here's a (standard) js version in 278 characters:

```
function winner(a,b){var c={rock:0,paper:1,scissors:2,spock:3,lizard:4},d="crushe,crushe,cover,disprove,cut,decapitate,smashe,vaporize,poison,eat".split(","),i=c[a],j=c[b],I=i==(j+3)%5;return i^j?i==(j+1)%5||I?a+" "+d[i*2+I]+"s "+b:b+" "+d[j*2+(j==(i+3)%5)]+"s "+a:a+" ties "+b}
```

Or one using E6 features (likely only works in Firefox) in 259 characters:

```
winner=(a,b,c={rock:0,paper:1,scissors:2,spock:3,lizard:4},d="crushe,crushe,cover,disprove,cut,decapitate,smashe,vaporize,poison,eat".split(","),i=c[a],j=c[b],I=i==(j+3)%5)=>i^j?i==(j+1)%5||I?a+" "+d[i*2+I]+"s "+b:b+" "+d[j*2+(j==(i+3)%5)]+"s "+a:a+" ties "+b
```